# Sum All Items in 3 Arrays (Strings) peer-to-peer

Tags: vbscript

I have 3 strings, and I want to sum peer-to-peer items by yearmonth.

```
string1 = "201402,10|201403,15|201404,25|201405,11|201406,23"
string2 = "201401,17|201402,25|201403,15|201404,12|201405,13|201406,9"
string3 = "201405,17|201406,25|201407,15|201408,12|201409,13|201410,9|201411,9|201412,9|201501,9"
```

to below result:

```
Result = "201401,10|201402,35|201403,30|201404,37|201405,41|201406,57|201407,15|201408,12|201409,13|201410,9|201411,9|201412,9|201501,9"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split each string at pipes, split each substring at commas, then use a dictionary to accumulate the values per year and month. Something like this should work:

```
string1 = "201402,10|201403,15|201404,25|201405,11|201406,23"
string2 = "201401,17|201402,25|201403,15|201404,12|201405,13|201406,9"
string3 = "201405,17|201406,25|201407,15|201408,12|201409,13|201410,9|201411,9|201412,9|201501,9"

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Sub Add(s)
  For Each line In Split(s, "|")
    v = Split(line, ",")
    d(v(0)) = d(v(0)) + CInt(v(1))
  Next
End Sub

Add string1
Add string2
Add string3

Set a = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each key In d.Keys
  a.Add key & "," & d(key)
Next
a.Sort
result = Join(a.ToArray, "|")

WScript.Echo result
```

Comment: Can you help me for Multi Strings?
maybe 3 string or 7 or 10 or 100?

Comment: I already wrote a script for you. Consider adapting it for a variable number of strings your homework. Hint: you need a list/array of strings and process that in a loop.