# Sum All Items in 3 Strings with 2 parameters

Tags: vbscript

In [The previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521977/sum-all-items-in-3-arrays-strings-peer-to-peer) we cam sum all item that yermonth are equals... But Now I Want sum all items that are Both parameters (yearmonth and prev value) (10,12,10) equal.
in the other words only sum Sting1 and String2 together.

I use `if v(0) = v(1) then` for new parameter limit, but it doesn't work.

```vb
string1 = "10,201402,10|10,201403,15|10,201404,25|10,201405,11|10,201406,23"
string2 = "10,201401,17|10,201402,25|10,201403,15|10,201404,12|10,201405,13|10,201406,9"
string3 = "12,201405,17|12,201406,25|12,201407,15|12,201408,12|12,201409,13|12,201410,9|12,201411,9|12,201412,9|12,201501,9"

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Sub Add(s)
  For Each line In Split(s, "|")
    v = Split(line, ",")
    if v(0) = v(1) then
       d(v(1)) = d(v(1)) + CInt(v(2))
    end if
  Next
End Sub

Add string1
Add string2
Add string3

Set a = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each key In d.Keys
  a.Add d(key) & "," & key & "," & d(key)
Next
a.Sort
result = Join(a.ToArray, "|")

WScript.Echo result
```

Actual result:

```
,10,|,12,|10,201402,10|11,201405,11|12,201408,12|13,201409,13|15,201403,15|15,201407,15|17,201401,17|23,201406,23|25,201404,25|9,201410,9|9,201411,9|9,201412,9|9,201501,9​
```

Desired result:

```
10,201401,17|10,201402,35|10,201403,30|10,201404,37|10,201405,24|10,201406,32
```

Comment: Result: Type mismatch: d(...)

Comment: it should work by : if v(0) = v(0) then... is this true?

Comment: New Result is: "12,201408,12|13,201409,13|15,201407,15|17,201401,17|30,201403,30|35,201402,35|37,201404,37|41,201405,41|57,201406,57|9,201410,9|9,201411,9|9,201412,9|9,201501,9".... and this is wrong...

Comment: What is the point of `v(0)=v(0)`? Isn't that always going to be true since it is the same thing on each side? Similarly, how does `d(v(1))` get initialized with a starting value here?

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers: realy you can't help me?!!

Comment: I'm Sorry for **Wrong** in my question. It's ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seriously doubt that you got any result if you actually used the condition `v(0) = v(1)`, because according to your sample data those values would never be equal.

If you want to sum values grouped by two parameters, you need to build the dictionary key from these two parameters:

```
For Each line In Split(s, "|")
  v = Split(line, ",")
  key = v(0) & "," & v(1)
  d(key) = d(key) + CInt(v(2))
Next
```

`v = Split(line, ",")` splits a record `10,201402,10` into an array with the 3 values `10`, `201402`, and `10`.

`key = v(0) & "," & v(1)` builds the key `10,2014` from the first 2 elements of that array.

`d(key) = d(key) + CInt(v(2))` converts the third value to an integer and adds it to the current value associated with the key `10,2014`.

Comment: Tanx Ansgar... i work and test your solution and come back