# Regular Expression, get pattern

Tags: vbscript

There is a log file called `abc.log` and it contains many lines in it like this:

```
Line 8123: Feb 01 19:44:40.961 | INFO | JEZHckpTehtA-ADSW4T14T5 | PROD | 10.86.99.108 | Feb 01 2016 19:44:29.595 | EVNT=SWIdmst|DQLN=YN| DQLN=EQUAL_QUAL_QUEUE_GOHEAD_IT
Line 8124: Feb 01 19:44:40.961 | INFO | JEZHckpTehtA-ADSW4T14T5 | PROD | 10.86.99.108 | Feb 01 2016 19:44:29.595 | EVNT=SWIdmst|DQLN=op.....
Line 8127: Feb 01 19:44:40.961 | INFO | JEZHckpTehtA-ADSW4T14T5 | PROD | 10.86.99.108 | Feb 01 2016 19:44:29.595 | EVNT=SWIdmst|DQLN=YN...........
Line 8129: Feb 01 19:44:40.961 | INFO | JEZHckpTehtA-ADSW4T14T5 | PROD | 10.86.99.108 | Feb 01 2016 19:44:29.595 | EVNT=SWIdmst|DQLN=YN| DQLN=Other_number
Line 8145: Feb 01 19:44:40.961 | INFO | JEZHckpTehtA-ADSW4T14T5 | PROD | 10.86.99.108 | Feb 01 2016 19:44:29.595 | EVNT=SWIdmst|DQLN=YN| Name=QID|Inputs=collname[allNum=12457845,oon=6842703020]|Outputid=00a4028a87c4473f,amid=2353.6,TransactionTime=125ms........
Line 8198: Feb 01 19:44:40.961 | INFO | JEZHckpTehtA-ADSW4T14T5 | PROD | 10.86.99.108 | Feb 01 2016 19:44:29.595 | End.....
```

I need to search `QUAL_QUEUE_GOHEAD_IT` in all the lines and get its ID `JEZHckpTehtA-ADSW4T14T5`. Then search that id in all lines and if `DQLN=Other_number` is found in a line starting with this ID and also `EOT_Dealer_PullAHead_ETQ` present in any of the line with same ID then
extract the line with `RuleName=GetPayoffInfo|Inputs=[accountNu.....`  present in the same id to another notepad.

I have the below code, it creates a new textpad but nothing is there in it and it says `nomatch` but the log file has all the strings mentioned in the code.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'create a new text file
Set word_found1 = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\hara\Desktop\tq\abc.log", True)

Set objFileToRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
    ("C:\Users\hara\Desktop\tq\testt1.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream
    strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadLine

    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "INFO \| ([^\|]*) \|.*QUAL_QUEUE_GOHEAD_IT"
    re.Global = True
    Set matches = re.Execute(strFileText)
    If matches.Count > 0 Then
        msg = "Found " & matches.Count & " matches:" & vbCRLF
        For Each match In Matches
            varid = match.SubMatches(0)
        Next
        word_found1.WriteLine strFileText
    Else
        MsgBox "No match", 0, "VBScript Regular Expression Tester"
    End If
Loop

objFileToRead.Close
```

Comment: Add some lines with **EOT_Dealer_PullAHead_ETQ** to your test data so that we can interpret your question correctly.

Comment: If the data is delimited, like it is in your sample data, then use Split instead of RegEx.

Comment: You'll get a no match msgbox for every line that doesn't have a match as you're testing this inside the loop. Try adding a `word_found1.Close()` after `objFileToRead.Close()` so that the write stream is flushed. Also have a flag that you set when you get a match. Then at the end if that flag has not been set then show your `No Match` messagebox

Comment: Can you please let me know how to get the id JEZHckpTehtA-ADSW4T14T5 by searching the string QUAL_QUEUE_GOHEAD_IT through split function.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33524133/1630171).

Comment: I have checked this link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521977/sum-all-items-in-3-arrays-strings-peer-to-peer/33524133#33524133`
I am not getting how to load the value after second delimiter in a line to a new variable, please help me out